# Facebook Page Tab app works on localserver but error 500 when deployed

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, sdk

I finished work on a facebook fan page tab app, working perfectly fine on loval server, as soon as i uploaded to heroku though, the app gives me an erro 500 message both on tab view and  in the heroku domain.

I'm not really a programmer so the code I am using comes from various tutorials, which makes me quite confiden that the error lies in either the php or JS i've used. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Will paste all the php and js code i got on the page see if anyone can find any errors

```
<?php
require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';
$app_id = "################";
$app_secret = "##########################";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>

<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId : '###############',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
</script>
<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response){
top.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/TAPPMedia/app_537955232907964/';
});
</script>

 <?php if ($like_status) { ?>
 <!-- Fan stuff here -->
 <?php } else { ?>
 <!-- Non_Fan stuff here -->
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? 
Have you made sure that the file you're including, is the correct path?

Which PHP versions are each servers running?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try and help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you answer the questions in my previous comment I will try and help further.

Comment: Hey sorry - my pc crashed! My localhost is on Php 5.4.16 and Heroku server is running Php 5.3.10. I think i can figure out how to get the log files from heroku.... and lastly I'm pretty confident the filepath is correct. Thanks!

Comment: ok my problem was all to do with not deploying properly and nothing to do with code... solved!